# Line feed in base64 encoded data

Tags: php, web-services, base64, httprequest

In a server sided script I am using the following PHP code to encode an image:

```
    $handle = fopen($imageSrc,'r');
    $file_content = fread($handle,filesize($imageSrc));
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded = base64_encode($file_content);

    echo $encoded;
```

When I read the file through a webservice it has the length 9309 bytes which is an invalid length for base64 encoded data. Examining the data, I found out that the value last byte is 10 (LF). Right now I am cropping the last byte away in my webservices before decoding the data. Is there a clean way to avoid the LF character to be sent?

Comment: Where is the code that actually sends the base64 encoded image?

Comment: echo $encoded;  actually sends the base64 data

Comment: If you include a `die();` directly after the final `echo`, does the `\n` still appear?

Comment: If I include a die(); after the eco, the \n disappears. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing this, but having debugged similar issues in the past, I would assume that there is something below the `echo` causing a `\n` to be output.

To test this, put a `die();` directly after the `echo`. If my theory is correct, you can either just leave the `die();`, or (better) move it progressively downwards in the execution flow until you find whatever is causing the `\n` to be output.